# Bash command in order to find common filename and cat their content

Tags: linux, bash, file, directory

Hello I have 3 directories such as :

**/path1/path2/pathA/path4/**

```
1_to_45.txt 
 ABC
1_to_46.txt
 DEF
1_to_47.txt 
 GHI
```

**/path1/path2/pathB/path4/**

```
1_to_45.txt 
 JKL
1_to_48.txt
 MNO
1_to_47.txt 
 PQR
```

**/path1/path2/pathC/path4/**

```
1_to_45.txt 
 STW
1_to_49.txt
 XYZ
1_to_47.txt 
 AUI
1_to_41.txt 
 IOP
```

And I would like to cat all file containt in common between the 3 directories into the `Merged_directory` directory and create files called the same way as the comme **filename**
so for exemple there are two files in common between the 3 directories :

**/path1/path2/Merged_directory**

```
    1_to_45.txt
        ABC
        JKL
        STW
    1_to_47.txt
        GHI
        PQR
        AUI
```

does someone have an idea ?

Comment: what your expectation if `1_to_48.txt` is also in `/path1/path2/pathC/path4/` ?

Comment: nothing, it as to be in all directories.

Comment: Soooo `cat /path1/path2/path*/*/1_to_45.txt > /path1/path2/Merged_directory/1_to_45.txt`?

Comment: no, it has to recognize filename matches....

Comment: Soo iterate over `for i in /path1/path2/path*/*/*.txt` - extract filename `basename $i` and then `cat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the filenames in one directory. Check if the corresponding name also exists in the other two directories. If so, cat them all into the merged directory.

```
dir1=/path1/path2/pathA/path4
dir2=/path1/path2/pathB/path4
dir3=/path1/path2/pathC/path4
merged=/path1/path2/Merged_directory
for file in "$dir1"/*.txt
do
    fn=${file##*/}
    if [ -f "$dir2/$fn" ] && [ -f "$dir3/$fn" ]
    then
        cat "$fn" "$dir2/$fn" "$dir3/$fn" > "$merged/$fn"
    fi
done
```

Comment: dir1 contains pathA so why "$dir1"/pathA/*.txt?

Comment: I had originally planned to just use a variable for the common prefix, then switched gears.